# Clipping in video converted by HandBrake

Tags: macos, video, hdvideo, ipad, handbrake

I own an iPad and an iPhone 4 and my Mac has a Dell UltraSharp 3008WFP 30-inch (2560x1600) display connected to it. I have a wealth of both 720p and 1080p ‘MKV’ videos of various television shows and movies and I wanted to convert them to a format that would be compatible with both my iOS-based devices and would also look great on my Mac’s display.

I started using HandBrake for converting episodes of my televisions shows. I made a new preset identical to the “High Profile” preset included by default and just changed the picture size to stay within 1280x720. The Constant Quality is set at 60.78% and everything else is also set at the default for the “High Profile” preset.

I’ve been using this setup for converting episodes of television shows for the past couple of months and it has worked great so far. However, when I try convert my 1080p movies using the same preset, the resultant movie ends up with horribly clipped audio throughout its length.

Can someone please help me out with this? I’ve tried four movies so far and all four have been rendered useless for me by the same problem. I’ve already wasted three days on this and don’t want to proceed until I’ve figured out how to fix this.

Is my preset wrong? Is there a more ideal setting for this? Should I bump up the Constant Quality to 80%, maybe?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you mean clipping - do you mean it's out of sync, too short, the volume is all over the place or it sounds like you're not getting all the audio?

The 1080p movies - do they have 5.1 (or 7.1) sound? In the Audio tab, are you downmixing the audio to stereo or leaving it as is?

The video conversion factor won't have any relation on the audio - check what the settings are in the audio tab. Of note, the iPad will only support stereo sound in AAC up to 320 kbps.